# Bash script error 127 Debian 11

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

I have a simple bash script that works as expected on Unbuntu 20 and LMDE 4. However, when I run it on Debian 11, it exits with error:

```
"choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)" command filed with exit code 127.
```

I am running it as root but I still get the error.
I also checked the code over at [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) and it said everything was good. This is a brand new install of Debian 11.

Any suggestions? I appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# exit when any command fails
set -e

# keep track of the last executed command
trap 'last_command=$current_command; current_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
# echo an error message before exiting
trap 'echo "\"${last_command}\" command filed with exit code $?."' EXIT

cmd=(dialog --separate-output --checklist "Select options:" 22 76 16)
options=(1 "Option 1" off    # any option can be set to default to "on"
         2 "Option 2" off
         3 "Option 3" off
         4 "Option 4" off)
choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
clear
for choice in $choices
do
    case $choice in
        1)  ls
            echo "First Option"
            ;;
        2)  pwd
            echo "Second Option"
            ;;
        3)  pwd
            echo "Third Option"
            ;;
        4)  ls -la
            echo "Fourth Option"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It suddenly hit me. It was dialog that was missing. I installed that and the script ran as expected.

Comment: Good catch. If this script is going to be run on multiple machines you might want an installation check somewhere near the top of the script. For example `if ! type dialog >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "ERROR: Missing 'dialog' - install it with ...{whatever}..." >&2; exit 1; fi`

Comment: Thank you. I will add that in.